# Getting very long, cryptic error output from RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, installation, rvm

I'm doing a fresh installation of RVM on my Macbook Air after having done what I thought was a complete uninstall from my system. Now, however, when I try to run "rvm get update", I receive the following lengthy output in Terminal:

```
Scotts-MacBook-Air:~ scotthollingsworth$ rvm get stable
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/scotthollingsworth/.profile /Users/scotthollingsworth/.bashrc /Users/scotthollingsworth/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/scotthollingsworth/.bash_profile /Users/scotthollingsworth/.zlogin.
Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsets./scripts/functions/gemset: line 118:  6633 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "${rvm_ruby_binary}" -rrubygems -e "$gem_spec" 2> /dev/null
Error running 'command gem install /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/log/1412613795_ruby-2.1.3/gem.install.rvm.log
[2014-10-06 11:43:15] command
current path: /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/src/rvm
GEM_HOME=/Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
PATH=/Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
command(7): command gem install /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc
+ ./scripts/functions/utility_logging : __rvm_log_dotted()  210 > gem install /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
Reason: image not found
./scripts/functions/utility_logging: line 210:  6658 Trace/BPT trap: 5  gem install
gem-wrappers -v >=1.2.4 --no-ri --no-rdoc

Upgrade of RVM in /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/ is complete.

# Scott Hollingsworth,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

RVM reloaded!
```

Does anyone know what this means, and how to fix the errors?

Comment: What is the issue? It says `Upgrade of RVM in /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/ is complete.`

Comment: Lines 5 through 18 of the code show two different errors: the first one says: "Error running 'command gem install /Users/scotthollingsworth/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc'"... and the following lines of code show the reasons behind it I believe. Any idea why this would happen? To be honest I'm not even sure what it indicates

Comment: I think the key will be: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib. Try googling that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be similar to the issue described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm). You can try using the solution provided in that answer.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed everything